# Building Android project using Jenkins throws com.android.dex.DexException while command line building works probably

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, emma

I'm using command ***ant clean debug emma install test*** to build my Android project with Apache Ant from command line and everything works perfectly (tests work and build becomes successful). While same command for Jenkins building (ANT, JAVA, ANDROID_SDK are configured) throws an error at the last build steps:

```
[dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] Result compacted from 9251,1KiB to 7638,5KiB to save 1612,5KiB
   [dx] Merged dex A (5330 defs/5673,8KiB) with dex B (2032 defs/1984,5KiB). Result is 7362 defs/7638,5KiB. Took 0,6s
   [dx] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/vladium/app/IAppVersion;
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
BUILD FAILED
/SDK/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:892: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/SDK/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/SDK/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:899: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/SDK/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:283: null returned: 2
```

Jenkins hosts on my local machine (which perfectly builds this project from command line) and I'm confused, why does this error occur. Looks like trouble in using emma.jar, but I can't find out, how to fix building project in Jenkins.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. We must execute command (word's order is very important):

```
ant clean emma debug install test
```

and exclude any emma libraries from our classpath (libs folder). Everything is quite easy.